# Get second last request for session in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

SessionInformation class from Spring Security have getLastRequest method which returns Date of last request for given session. Is there a possibility to get date of second last request for this session.
Or is there a way to place filter in such way that it will get all requests on specific path before lastRequest is updated?

Comment: I have two separate apps that both authenticate on one server. Both of them have a feature that after given time of inactivity in browser send request to the server to log out. It should log user out from both applications. But it should do it only if he was idle in both apps, so i need to check if any other app didn't make a request using same session. Getting last request would be ideal for this, but the problem is that if i send request to check last request date it automatically updates date to current time thus preventing me from getting needed information.

Comment: Then don't set and a request and create an option to query the `SessionInformation` without issuing a request.